# How can I deal with weird result? XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX not working

Tags: latex, tex, miktex, xelatex

So, I have been using TeXstudio for my LaTeX documents and MiKTeX 2.9. I opened some documents that I created in the past and I see that using XeLateX a weird result at the top of the first page is visible, and I could not find anything similar on Google. So after that I tried with LuaLateX but this never produced a .pdf and gave me a number of errors.

[Result with XeLateX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XUHF.png)

I thought that it might had something to do with the environment variables in Windows because I installed Python yesterday, but I have changed this many times. Also I reinstalled both MiKTeX and Texstudio. Any specific help, or in general? Thanks.

UPDATE:

I have deleted all the files before and even copied and pasted the file in a new folder to run it like a new project. I forgot to point out that probably a part of the problem is the \usepackage{xltxtra}. For instance with XeLaTeX, when running the code below, the result is normal.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
    This is some random text for preview purposes. 
\end{document}
```

But using `\usepackage{xltxtra}` the result is same as the one pointed in the question.

Comment: Try to delete all auxiliary files and compile again with xelatex. If this does not help, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and also show the complete error message you get from the log file

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for answering, I have updated the question.I will try to show the errors but the messages are too many and there were errors before, even when the pdf was exported correctly

Comment: Thanks for adding this example. It works fine for me both with and without `xltxtra`. Can you show your .log file? (if it is too long to add to your question, you could post it on https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: So, I reinstalled MikTeX for the 3rd time and it worked out for some reason. Not sure if it had to do with the version of it. The previous one looked like a bug to me. Thanks for your time.